# BlazeMeter Chrome extension not recording call to fill table

Tags: ajax, web, jmeter, blazemeter

I am currently working on making a JMeter test for my company's website. I've been using the BlazeMeter Chrome extension to record http requests because I haven't been able to get the certificate working for the JMeter 2.11 proxy server.

On one of the site's main pages there is a large table that is filled by what I believe is an AJAX call. I use the extension to record using the page and add the recorded http requests to my test. However, when I run the test with those requests, none of the requests get responses that are anywhere near long enough to fill the table.

I made sure that the BlazeMeter extension is not just recording high-level requests, and that the cache is disabled. I know that the data is not sent with the initial html page because I can see that the table element is initially empty. Does the BlazeMeter extension not record every request? Or am I wrong to assume that the table is filled by and AJAX call? Or is there another protocol I'm missing entirely?

Comment: <I work for BlazeMeter> If record only high level requests is unchecked the plugin will indeed record EVERY request. I would suggest using the chrome developer tools -> network tab to investigate if the request is indeed AJAX or something else.

Comment: Can you share the URL of the page in question?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. It's the kind of website only our company's clients have access to.

Comment: Look at the network view in developer tools in chrome to see every network request. You can then compare that to the list of requests you're seeing in the session recording created by the BlazeMeter plugin. They should be identical.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by analyzing the actual HTTP requests themselves. At the end of the day ANY performance tool you use to record browser activity is only going to record and playback the requests.

Is there an actual request that you can see your browser making that is not being recorded by the BlazeMeter chrome plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Play with below options in "Advanced Options" of extension to see all calls.
[image]